# Prove that the sequence defined as $x_{n+1}=\frac{2x_n+5}{6}, x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, induction

Prove that the sequence $(x_n)$ defined as $x_{n+1}=\frac{2x_n+5}{6}, x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ converges.
I would like to have a feedback if my proof is correct, please)

To show that $(x_n)$ converges, we have to show that it is bounded and monotonic.

First we show by induction that the sequence is increasing. Suppose $x_{n+1}>x_n$. The previous inequality is true for $n=0$, because $1/2<1$. So we can suppose that the inequality holds $\forall n\ge0$. Now we have to show that it works for $n+1$. So, we would like to show that $x_{n+2}>x_{n+1} \ \forall n\ge 0$. But by our induction hypothesis we have that:

$x_{n+1}>x_n \iff 2x_{n+1}>2x_n \iff \dfrac{2x_{n+1}+5}{6}>\dfrac{2x_n+5}{6} \iff x_{n+2}>x_{n+1}$

So we conclued that $x_{n+2}>x_{n+1}$ is true $\forall n\ge0$

We show right now that $(x_n)$ is bounded above. Suppose that $x_n<2$. The inequality holds for $n=0$, so we can suppose that $x_n<2$ is true $\forall n\ge0$. We want to show that it is true for $n+1$, i.e $x_{n+1}<2$. By induction hypothesis we have:

$x_n<2 \iff 2x_n<4 \iff 2x_n+5<9 \iff \frac{2x_n+5}{6}<\frac{9}{6}<2 \iff x_{n+1}<2 \ \forall n\ge0$

as wanted.

So we showed that the sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent.

Comment: When you prepare for the induction step you always write "suppose that it is true $\forall n$", but that is what you like to prove. $\forall$ means for all. Write something like "it is true up to a certain $n$". I would avoid the use of $\forall$.

Comment: Two inductions applied well.

Comment: @Gary Thank you for this advice, further i will pay attention to it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $ \{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ converges to $ L $, then

$$L=\frac{2L+5}{6} \iff L=\frac 54$$

$$x_{n+1}-\frac 54=\frac{2x_n+5}{6}-\frac 54$$
$$=\frac 13\left(x_n-\frac 54\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac 13\right)^2\left(x_{n-1}-\frac 54\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac 13\right)^{n+1}\left(x_0-\frac 54\right)$$
$$=-\frac 14\left(\frac 13\right)^n$$

the limit is $L=\frac 54$.

Comment: $ x_0=\frac 12$.